# create multiple plots from paired x and y axis variables from single data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, apply

Is there any way to create multiple bar plots from a single dataframe without melting the data?

here is the data:

```
    crap <- tribble(~Person, ~Group, ~Measurement_1, ~Measurement_2, ~Measurement_3,
                    "Alex","A",14.6,52,115,
                    "Alex","B",12.3,63,116,
                    "Alex","C",15.5,45,186,
                    "Alex","D",16.3,35,146,
                    "Alex","E",18.7,66,149,
                    "Dante","A",19.6,57,185,
                    "Dante","B",15.2,75,187,
                    "Dante","C",12.9,64,199,
                    "Dante","D",11.3,69,142,
                    "Dante","E",13.4,43,134,
                    "Dante","A",18.7,44,132,
                    "Clyde","B",12.9,62,135,
                    "Clyde","C",11.5,65,165,
                    "Clyde","D",10.5,60,183,
                    "Clyde","E",11.9,55,145)
```

First is I reordered the `Preson` column based on the values of `Measurement_1, Measurement_2, Measurement_3` using this code:

```
    karl <- crap %>% 
      mutate(reorder_M1 = fct_reorder(Person, Measurement_1)) %>%
      mutate(reorder_M2 = fct_reorder(Person, Measurement_2)) %>%
      mutate(reorder_M3 = fct_reorder(Person, Measurement_3))
```

After reordering, i tried creating bar plots.
I tried `using ggplot2` but my codes cannot recognize the pairing of the columns. I also tried using `ggbarplot()` but it also cannot recognize the paring of the columns.

here are the codes that I have tried.

```
    plot_crap <- ggbarplot(data = crap, x = c("reorder_M1", "reorder_M2", "reorder_M3"),
                                    y = c("Measurement_1", "Measurement_2","Measurement_3"),
                                    combine = TRUE, 
                                    x.text.angle = 360, 
                                    orientation = "horizontal",
                                    ylab = "Measurement (cm)", 
                                    xlab = "Person", 
                                    color = "Group",
                                    fill = "Group", 
                                 ggtheme = theme_gray()) + 
                                  font("xy.text", size = 7, color = "black") + 
                                  theme(legend.position = "None", 
                                  axis.text.x =element_text(color = "black")))
```

Is there any way to automate creation of multiple plots all in one block of code.

The pairing would be:

x = reorder_M1 and y = Measurement_1

x = reorder_M2 and y = Measurement_2

x = reorder_M3 and y = Measurement_3

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to reshape the data? What you want is possible, but requires some reshaping.

Comment: @jdobres I have been trying to understand how to melt the data to reshape it, unfortunately, I can't get the codes right and would not come up with correct reshaping. Can you explain to me how to properly reshape the data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exaclty what you want. But here I created multiple bar plots using `ggbarplot` without melting the dataframe. You can use this code:

```
library(ggpubr)
  plot_crap <- ggbarplot(data = crap, x = "Person",
                         y = c("Measurement_1", "Measurement_2","Measurement_3"),
                         combine = TRUE, 
                         x.text.angle = 360, 
                         orientation = "horizontal",
                         ylab = "Measurement (cm)", 
                         xlab = "Person", 
                         color = "Group",
                         fill = "Group", 
                         ggtheme = theme_gray()) + 
    font("xy.text", size = 7, color = "black") + 
    theme(#legend.position = "None", 
          axis.text.x =element_text(color = "black"))
  
  plot_crap
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Actually, doing this is great, however, i created another columns using `fct_reorder()` to rearrange the x variables. doing your solution would not make the `Person` in increasing order. Is there anyway to di it? why would x variable be not automatically paired with the y variable given that they are equal in length?

Comment: @TylerRuddenfort, Aren't the `Person` column and the new columns in the exact rearrange order if you check the `karl` table?

Comment: Actually, that confuses me as well. when you view the table, they seem to be in the same order, but when plotted, they rearrange in increasing order. based on what I have read in the documentation, `fct_reorder` can rearrange a particular column based on another column either by mean, median, or mode.